# Docker run without setting WORKDIR doesn't work

Tags: docker

This doesn't work：

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 image /go/src/hello
```

This works:

```
docker run -w /go/src/ -d -p 80:80 image ./hello
```

I'm confused about the above result.
I prefer the first one but it doesn't work. Anyone can help with this.

Comment: Could you show the logs?

Comment: user@vultr:~$ docker logs d4aa3af71c27
2016/02/13 15:59:31 [asm_amd64.s:1998][I] http server Running on :8080-------------The logs as above looks normal. It's a basic (golang) http server, and I failed to "curl localhost:8080". But if I use "docker run -w /go/src/hello -d -p 80:80 image ./hello", it works.  (/go/usr/hello/hello is a executable file).

Comment: @Clerk what log is this? The one from the container where it did not work? (and if not, what were the log of the container which did not work?)

Comment: I use the command:  "docker logs testimage".

Comment: @Clerk You should have one image, but *two* containers: one in Exited mode (because it failed) and one working (state run) see `docker ps -a`

Comment: @VonC I tried a lot, and found it's weird: (1) I used "docker run -it AnOfficialImage" to create the ContainerA. (2) I used "docker commit ContainerA TestImage" to create the TestImage. (3) Then I used "docker run -d -p 80:80 TestImage /go/src/hello/hello" to create Container B. (4) The problem is " the work I did in ContainerA doesn't take effect.

Comment: @Clerk That is not how a golang official image is used: you set a Dockerfile starting FROM it, COPY some src files, compile your program and *that* gives you an images with the executable in in bin folder.

Comment: @VonC I thought Docker File is just an alternative. But I need to revise it for many layers, so I have to write docker file for each time?

Comment: It is not an alternative indeed. It is the main reason to use Docker in the first place: a Dockerfile allows you to specify images that you can rebuild in a repeatable fashion.

Comment: You only write *one* Dockerfile which  will include all the commands you need to generate your executable.

Comment: I made it now. I use the second one setting workdir  in dockerfile and it works. The first one doesn't work and I decide to let it go.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `ENTRYPOINT` (you can see it with a `docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' image`)

With a default `ENTRYPOINT` of `sh -c`, both should work.
With any other `ENTRYPOINT`, it might expect to be in the right folder before doing anything.

Also a `docker log <container>` would be helpful to know what the first try did emit as an output.

As The [OP Clerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126615/clerk) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380134/docker-run-without-setting-workdir-doesnt-work/35380260?noredirect=1#comment58468975_35380260), it is from a [golang Dockerfile/image](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/79e2ef7426433df214a0592cc49b7544658811b2/1.6/alpine/Dockerfile), which means 'hello' will refer to a compiled `hello` executable in `$GOPATH/bin` or to an executable built with go build in the `src` folder.

Comment: I tried docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' image, and the result is nil.

Comment: @Clerk Then fallback to `docker inspect <image>|grep -i entrypoint` But of course, replace '`<image>`' by the name of the actual image.

Comment: I tried and it's nil.  I know some other images have results like {[/entrypoint.sh]}. But this one was nil ( I revise from the official golang image to create my own image).